# Eclipse - cancel automatic switch to debug view

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have accidentally set in the past the eclipse to switch to debug view when break point is  hit.
How do i cancel that, meaning make it manually

thanks

Comment: **Note** that neither of these solutions work. Only real solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27507568/1599699

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Uncheck:

> Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Activate the debug view when a breakpoint is hit

Also go to

> Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives

And select either "never" or "prompt" in "Open associated perspective..."

Comment: Oops, really sorry, but i thought is was stopped. still jumping. (Eclipse 3.6)

Comment: @fatnjazzy there are other similar checkboxes there. Try them. But this one should really be it.

Comment: This answer is not correct. But the one from @Stjn is!

Answer (score 8):

In your question you speak of a debug 'view', but I think you are actually referring to the debug 'perspective'. If not, just disregard my answer.

To stop Eclipse from switching to the Debug perspective when a breakpoint is hit:

> Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives -> 'Open the
>   associated perspective when an application suspends' -> Never

The Debug View is the window that shows the running application, it's threads and each thread's call stack in a tree view and gives you little 'play', 'pause', 'stop' etc buttons for things like Resume, Suspend, Terminate. I think the option referred to by the accepted answer tells Eclipse whether it should make this view the active view (within whatever perspective is set to open in debug mode) when a breakpoint is hit. Probably you do want that to be enabled...