# Stop Eclipse from automatically opening the debug perspective when starting server in debugging mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging, perspective

There are several examples on stack overflow of how to enable/disable the debug perspective from opening when the **debugger activates** (i.e., hits a breakpoint).  This would be achieved by going to:

Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives -> Open the associated perspective when application suspends

My question is not about this.  Whenever I **start my server** in debug mode, the debug perspective opens.  Since I already have the debug view open in my custom perspective, this is not the behavior I want.  I've tried editing every option in Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives, so I know the answer is not there.  Does anyone know how to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a simple workaround that obtains the same result.  I now use the "Debug" perspective itself as my main perspective.  I've customized the "Debug" perspective to look like the custom perspective I used to use. Now this perspective is the only one that is ever open and I can keep the IDE looking like how I want it to look.

Comment: this is not a fix to the problem posted and using a perspective for something it was not meant to is far from optimal

Comment: The problem hasn't a fix!
I tried in many ways to tell Eclipse to not switch to the damn debug perpective. Simply there's no way to avoid that.
So i conclude that this is the  solution and that i hate Eclipse.

Comment: Ingenious! And they are correct. I too have tried everything.